# IIS: Modify origin server in order to manage X-Forwarded-Host (XFH)

Tags: iis

I need to do this in IIS but I do not know how.

Here is how it is done in Nginx and Apache:

**Nginx:**

```
location / {
    if ( $http_x_forwarded_host = alias.example.com ) {
        root /path/to/website/alias1/;
    }
}
```

**Apache:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}" "alias\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/sub/path/$1" [PT]
```

The examples are copied from: https://www.keycdn.com/support/manage-multiple-websites-with-one-zone/

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you might need is very similar to this:

```
    <rewrite>
        <allowedServerVariables>
            <add name="X-FORWARDED-HOST" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
        <rewriteMaps>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <globalRules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="HTTPS ReWrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/sub/path/{R:1} />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST}" pattern="alias.example.com" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```